# latexmk cannot find perl

Tags: latexmk

I have installed `latexmk` and ActiveState Perl, which is in C:/perl/bin. I also have a `.latexmkrc` (<- a file with the extension .latexmkrc; I'm not sure if this is what I was supposed to do) file in the same directory as `latexmk`. I am using TexStudio and Miktex, and when I try to compile using latexmk ( latexmk.exe -pdf -silent -synctex=1 "document") it gives me an error, saying: `: The script engine could not be found. latexmk.exe: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe"`, even though I have already installed perl.  How should I attempt to fix this?

Comment: Try on the command line. Don't use `-silent` for testing. If you try `perl --version` on the command line, is the executable found? If not, it seems not to be in your path (or whatever the Windows equivalent of a path is).

Comment: @cfr without `-silent` the error persists (I used latexmk document.tex). Trying `persion --version`, the executable is found. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: The point of removing `-silent` is not to make the error go away but to make it not hide potentially useful diagnostic information from you. Do you mean that `perl --version` found `perl`?

Comment: Yes, `perl --version` found `perl`. Without `-silent`, the same statement is given and there are no additional statements.

Comment: This needs a Windows person. I don't know how `latexmk` (or anything else) finds `perl` on Windows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about TeX, but a bad installed computer system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you have more than one version of perl installed. In your path settings the wrong one will be find first. Most likley the reason for your task.

Check path settings on your machine...

Comment: I once had strawberry perl installed, but I uninstalled it before installing ActiveState Perl. It is the only version installed currently

Answer (score 3):

Hmm. After resetting my computer, everything was fixed. No additional steps were taken.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem on Windows but with an entirely different root cause.

After installing some new software the `latexmk` build failed with the question's error message:

```
latexmk.exe: The script engine could not be found.
latexmk.exe: Data: scriptEngine="perl.exe"
```

The installed software had inserted into the head of my `PATH` and also inserted an extra `;` after its variables. `latexmk` seems to have a problem parsing the path to find `perl.exe` if an empty variable is provided, even though `perl.exe` was still on my `PATH` and I could call it from the command line.